# How to create clipping mask using displacement map?

Tags: texturing, displacement

how I can hide certain part of mesh using only the node editor. For example, how I can make the cross-bonding black part of the map invisible in the mesh using only the node editor.
[image: displacement map clipping]

Answer (score 1):

add a mix shader between the material output and the principled shader. add a transparent shader, and plug it into the other input of the mix shader. take your the map you want to act as a mask, and plug it into the factor input of the mix shader.

I hope this helps, and please comment if you need more info.

Comment: thank you very much, that was very helpful.

Comment: I'm glad my answer was useful.